# How to I see file's github commit history by line-by-line

Tags: github

[image]

If I add this file at commit "aaaaa"

and change some line at commit "abcde"

and change some line at commit "qwert".

some of "qwert" change is already changed at "abcde", but it shows "qwert" because latest change commit is "qwert".

I looked at the documentation of git log.

"git log" shows each commit change.

I don't think it will work with just one command, but I don't know what to do.

How can I get like this?

command line, shell script or other programs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame

git blame 
is what I want.

It gives like "commit author date linenumber content" by line by line

```
97155223 (GiukViral 2022-10-26 11:02:37 +0900 38)
8ddfd064 (GiukViral 2022-10-28 21:13:12 +0900 39) interface PreDefinedExtractors {
8ddfd064 (GiukViral 2022-10-28 21:13:12 +0900 40)   [page: string]: PageExtractor
03c4cade (GiukViral 2022-10-26 18:25:16 +0900 41) }
03c4cade (GiukViral 2022-10-26 18:25:16 +0900 42)
```